# Ebean LEFT JOIN with condition on right side

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I'm using Java / Play 2.4 / Ebean and I need to find all the records in table A that does not have a corresponding record in table B.

This is the SQL I'd like Ebean to generate:

```
select a.*
from a
left join b
on a.b_id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

I thought this might be the right code but it's not:

```
A = Ebean.find(models.A.class).fetch("bs").where().isNull("bs.id").findList();
```

By fetching all the b's for table A (i.e. "bs") Ebean adds a left outer join on b. Unfortunately, the where() causes another (inner) join to table b. Something like this:

```
select a.*
from a
left outer join b
on a.b_id = b.id
join b
on a.b_id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

Obviously this wont work.

How does an Ebean user do a left join with a condition on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Ebean but in many cases I prefer to have a good control on the queries. As you have a LEFT JOIN and some condition, I would count your case towards the 'not-that-trivial' ones.

1. How about using an **SqlQuery**?

   ```
   final String sql = "select a.* from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id where b.id is null";

   SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);

   // execute the query returning a List of MapBean objects
   List<SqlRow> list = sqlQuery.findList();
   ```

   Then you can work with the [SqlRow](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/SqlRow.html) objects and extract the data you need
2. Or using a **RawSql** object? You can generate one using the [RawSqlBuilder](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/RawSqlBuilder.html#parse-java.lang.String-). Then use something like: `Ebean.find(models.A.class).setRawSql(...).findList();`

---

*Edit:*
I am not an SQL expert but shouldn't it be something like:

original:

`select a.* from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id where b.id is null`

change to:

`select a.* from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id and b.id is null`

So that you have the `where` condition inside the join. And then try again the RawSqlBuilder#parse()

Comment: Thanks I have been trying #2 but havent gotten it to work properly. There are two methods- with RaqlSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create() I get the correct results but its very slow- its doing one query per row from the first query trying to fetch table B for each A.ID individually. with unparse() I get the error: [PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Invalid column index.  I'll go to straight sql if I have to but it means either creating the objects individually (SLOW) or considerable changes to my views to not use the real objects anymore. In which case, why even use an ORM?

Comment: Actually, now that I look more closely, when I use parse() its not the find(models.A.class).setRawSql(rsql).findList() that is causing the one-query-per-id to happen... it must be in the view. Maybe my rsql is missing something the view needs...

Comment: Were you able to track down the performance loss? I updated my answer with another thought of mine - regarding the SQL statement

Comment: Those queries give the same results although it might affect how the execution plan is built in the db. Yes, I found the performance issue. Everything in the controller is fine. But later, in the view, there is a datatable showing data from both tables a and b. When displaying all records this works fine because in my controller for the "show all" case their is a fetch("b") which hints that b should be joined in that one query. However, in the "show all a that dont have corresponding b" case the view tries to fetch b.property for each a record. I havent fixed this yet...

Comment: Also, there is an IRC channel on irc.freenode.net called #playframework. Activity is low at times when I am active but there are experts in there.